# ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RED'. Only affecting one chapter

Tags: color

I am using the document class `book` and this error started popping up, It is only affecting one chapter, the others I can use the colour red fine.

The line is: `\section{\color{red}Section Title}`

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I assume the `\MakeUppercase` problem here, i.e. `red` is made into `RED`.

Answer (score 8):

Section titles are sometimes made uppercase. Then the uppercase command (`\MakeUppercase` or `\uppercase`) also converts the argument of `\color` to uppercase:

```
\color{red} => \color{RED}
```

Workarounds:

- Defining color `RED`, e.g.:

  ```
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \colorlet{RED}{red}
  ```
- Hiding the color command as protected macro, e.g.:

  ```
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\myred}{\color{red}}
  ```

  or with e-TeX's `\protected`:

  ```
  \protected\def\myred{\color{red}}
  ```

  In both cases `\myred` is to be used in the section title instead of `\color{red}`. The latter case of `\protected` also works with `\uppercase`, the former does not.

Comment: Please, avoid answering duplicate questions, particularly if you had already answered a similar question.